# Win32Service Extension for PHP 5.4.12

Tags: php, nginx

I am currently running PHP 5.4.12 and cannot find a compatible php_win32service.dll to download. All the ones that I have seen seem to be for PHP 5.2/5.3?

When trying to use the dll made for these versions, I get the following error message:

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_win32service.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

It is worth pointing out that I have put the dll in the correct place along with the other extensions!

Please can somebody give me any advice on where to go from here?

Thanks in advance.
Joe

Comment: Take a look here. Maybe you will be lucky! http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ or try to build it from http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/win32service/

Comment: No such luck finding an already built version! Do I need to download a C compiler to build the svn versions? Have you done this before? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I don't have that much experience with the windows platform. But yes! You need a compiler. Most info on compiling for windows should be available here https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: Thanks I will try this... Failing this I might revert to an earlier version of PHP as I don't think there is anything specific that I am using from the newer version it's all pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I have gone with simply using php version 5.3.23 with the hope that I could simply steal one of the pre-built dll's from the site you mentioned. I am still getting the same error. Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: I have a working version now: php_win32service-svn20091206-5.3-vc9-x86.zip seemed to do the job! WooHoo!

Answer (score 2):

Versions for PHP 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 can be found at
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/win32service/0.1.0/

This is also a good source for many other Windows PHP extensions:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

Complete builds of PHP for Windows with other extensions are regularly published at
http://www.apachelounge.com/viewforum.php?f=6